# Multiple functions with same controller

Tags: c++, arduino

I'm on a project using arduinos.This is my idea:
I have a squared signal that can slightly change. This signal gives me 58 pulses and then 2 empty spaces, indicating the cycle's beginning.
My objective is to generate another signal that changes according to this one.
My idea is to first get a sample of the signal for each X time, to get the number of pulses.After this, I want to read my cycle's start, to be able to know where my signal is every time.Then I'll generate my signal depending on that.
My problem is that I think I'll need a loop for getting my sample, which lasts as long as the pulse of the signal that I want to generate, or probably even longer, and another loop for detecting my start.
Is there any way of doing this with the same chip?Or my function is always gonna get stuck with the sample instead of generating my pulses?
Thanks!

Comment: 1) Please format this wall of test 2) What have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes it is possible, and there are a lot of way to solve this problem.

I would use a state machine.
In the first state, you are waiting for your "start", so you do a pulseln() on the input pin, if the pulase duration is good you'll increase a variable, if not reset that variable.
After that look at variabile value: if it is 56 you enter the second state.

In the second state you do what you have to do, and eventually fall back to state 1 (waiting a new "start") or enter another state.

As you can see, that approach is good if you have a finite (and relativly small) number of state, like a protocol. You can just use the code from state 1 if you need only to do something after the "start" and go backj to wait "start"